Integrating User Feedback
How can designers strategically integrate user feedback into the iterative design process to ensure products meet both functional needs and aesthetic preferences effectively?

Hey Tim. Welcome! This is too broad of a question for a Q&A format like this. It might help if you add a bit of context to why you're asking this question

Normally is done by an A-B test.
You have two options, and then evaluate the user interaction using different methods.
In the old days, you asked: What do you prefer, A or B?

But nowadays you can evaluate for example measuring the time a user is interacting with your interface, for example

How long he stays using it.
How fast he stops using it.
What miniature did he click first, etc.

You need some analytics software installed to measure that.

It is a bit complex because you need to define what is the difference between A and B, it could be something simple like a Light Theme vs a dark theme, but if you mix too many changes it would be not easy to evaluate what had the most impact.
So it would be best if you made several tests, hoping not to make your audience tired.

To humans is easier to eliminate what they do not like than choosing what they like. So a way to test, when you have more than 2 options, for example 3 different color schemes is asking.
Which one you don't like? Choose 1.
Then you can ask for the one they like most of the remaining 2.

It is a matter of psychology and behavior analysis. This is a tool on the realm of marketing, applied to design decisions.

Good answer to a horrible, no-effort, question.
